# React to url change within component with React Router 4?

Tags: react-router-v4

I have a component available at different urls. This is a simplified version of my app.js

```
<Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/login"
               render={() => {
                    return <SignUpAndRegister status="login" />;
                }}
            </Route>
            <Route path="/register"
                render={() => {
                    return <SignUpAndRegister status="register" />;
                }}
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    <Router>
```

I pass the status prop and then in the component setState based on the prop value. This works so far but I also need Links within the component that link to other other state. When your on the register page/state I have a link to login. When you're on the login page/state I have a link to register.

This means I have to have a link to change the url and also call a function to setState:

```
    <Link
      to="/login"
      onClick={() => this.registerOrLogin('login')}
      >
        Log in
    </Link>
```

How can I have the components state change when a url change is detected? It seems like browserHistory did this prior to v4 but I cant find an up up date solution.

Comment: Just `<Link to="/login">Log in</Link>` doesn't update the URL and reload the component for you with correct state?

Comment: No, would you expect it to?

Comment: Yes. Where are you importing `Link` component from?

Comment: From React Router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can set the state within the SignUpAndRegister component when it first mounts and then every time new props are received eg when the url changes.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ status: this.props.status });
}

componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setState({ status: props.status });
}
```