# React router4: update state at onClick Link component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, reactstrap

I have a Route component that will render a row of table based on the current url, the problem is i can't update state with onClick that i put on Link component, the url is changed but the state is still the same, so the rendered row content is still the same, look at this code bewlow:

```
      <Route
        exact
        path={'/dashboard/:page'}
        render={() => (
          this.state.data &&
            data.map((data, index) =>
            <Row key={index}>
               <Col md="1" xl="1">{index + 1}</Col>
               <Col md="3" xl="4">{data.job_title}</Col>
               <Col md="2" xl="3">{data.city}</Col>
               <Col md="2" xl="2">{data.job_status}</Col>
               <Col md="2" xl="2"><a href="">{data.inbox.length > 1 ? data.inbox + ' Candidates' : data.inbox + ' Candidate'}</a></Col>
            </Row>
          )
        )}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path={'/dashboard'}
        render={() => (
          this.state.data &&
            data.map((data, index) =>
            <Row key={index}>
               <Col md="1" xl="1">{index + 1}</Col>
               <Col md="3" xl="4">{data.job_title}</Col>
               <Col md="2" xl="3">{data.city}</Col>
               <Col md="2" xl="2">{data.job_status}</Col>
               <Col md="2" xl="2"><a href="">{data.inbox.length > 1 ? data.inbox + ' Candidates' : data.inbox + ' Candidate'}</a></Col>
            </Row>
          )
        )}
      />
    </div>
    <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Link onClick={() => {this.setState({currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1, data: dataMock.data[this.state.currentPage + 1]})}} to="/dashboard/1">
        <Button style={{margin: '20px'}}>Page + 1</Button>
      </Link>
      <Link onClick={() => {this.setState({currentPage: this.state.currentPage - 1, data: dataMock.data[this.state.currentPage - 1]})}} to='/dashboard/2'>
        <Button style={{margin: '20px'}}>Page - 1</Button>
      </Link>
    </div>
```

the question is how can i update the state with the new one? it seems the state is not updated, am i doing it wrong? and i'm a bit confused with this solution i found earlier, here's the link: [React to url change within component with React Router 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49913058/react-to-url-change-within-component-with-react-router-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not usre if that's a good practise. But an easier fix would be
Add the click event to the button, then onClick, do the setState, on setState's call back `this.props.history.push('Route')`

for example,

```
takeUserToPage = () => {
  this.setState({currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1, data: 
   dataMock.data[this.state.currentPage + 1]}, () => {
   this.props.history.push('Route')
  });
}

//inside your return
 <Button style={{margin: '20px'}} onClick={this.takeUserToPage}>Page + 1</Button>
```